# How to know if a session has been set

Tags: c#, asp.net

In php i used to use

```
session_start();
if(isset(SESSION["user"]))
{
   //session is set
}
els{
    // there is no session 
}
```

but do i do that in asp.net? I mean. What code can tells wheather a session is set or not

ex:
asp.net c#

```
//login.aspx
SESSION["USER"];

//user_profile.aspx
if(SESSION["USER"])// how do i validate that??
{

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SESSION["USER"]; //this should throw an error since it's not setting a value and not a method.
```

You can test your session values like this:

```
if (Session["USER"] != null)
{
    //do something interesting
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for the existance of a session variable this will be fine:

```
if(Session["USER"] != null)
{
    //If you get here a session variable "USER" exists...
}
```

Though [it is possible to disable session state](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996) in an asp.net application it is very rare to see that.

Answer (score 2):

From php side, cince **[*isset*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Just check if this session `null` or not like:

```
if(Session["USER"] != null)
{
  // Do something
}
```