# Checking if session is null causes exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have the following line of code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SESSION_USER] = user;
```

Which is causing an exception, I assume because the session is null.

If I remove this line, the exception does not get thrown.

I am able to retrieve the ID from the `user` object, so I assume that is not what is causing the problem.

From this question:

[How to know if a session has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076567/how-to-know-if-a-session-has-been-set)

I tried the following:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SESSION_USER] == null)
    throw new Exception("SESSIONULL");
else
    throw new Exception("SESSIONOTNULL");
```

But neither of these exceptions get thrown - I assume because it is trying to access a null object so throws before it gets to execute my code.

If so, how can I tell if the session is null, I know I can use a try catch block as this stops the error, but I would prefer to resolve this in a more precise manner.

any ideas?

EDIT: this was not a duplicate of the question above, as the question above is trying to access a variable from within the session, I needed to check if the actual session was null. Se my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine a session variable is null or empty in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234973/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-a-session-variable-is-null-or-empty-in-c)

Comment: @QuentinRoger can you see my response to your duplicate comment, and if you agree remove the duplicate tag please

Comment: @Alex I'd argue the question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-object-is-null-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ardila can you explain how that is the case? The answer to my question relaties to the level of the variable to examine for a null value, if I apply the  answer to the question you link to, using the variable in my original question, I wills till receive a null exception. Is what I am saying correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: @Alex knowing what object should be checked against null is not a good question as no canonical answer can exist for every program. Therefore knowing how to check for null *is* the canonical answer. Btw, your title should be "Checking if Session is null". Also of interest [What should I do if the current ASP.NET session is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/what-should-i-do-if-the-current-asp-net-session-is-null/1382811#1382811), which includes how to check for a null `Session` object.

Comment: @ardila I will have to respectfully disagree - my answer below is not an opinion, it is the correct answer, and solved the problem. The answer was clearly that the session was null so it could not check a session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wast trying to access a variable from a null session, so it could never check for the variable because the session was null.

The solution is as follows:

```
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SESSION_USER] = user;
            }
```

This now checks the actual session, rather than the variable.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SESSION_USER]))
{
//for session is available
}
```

Comment: This will also throw if `Session == null`